# Why canvas is not showing up?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter. Can anyone please tell me why the canvas is not showing up? I'm not getting any errors so I assume it is working but just not visible?

It was a snake game program. Can someone please help me? The canvas was supposed to change the color of the window and the size.

The following is the code:

```py
import tkinter
import random

ROWS = 25
COLS = 25
TILE_SIZE = 25

WINDOW_WIDTH = TILE_SIZE * ROWS
WINDOW_HEIGHT = TILE_SIZE * COLS

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Snake")
window.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(
    window,
    bg="black",
    width=WINDOW_WIDTH,
    height=WINDOW_HEIGHT,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
)
canvas.pack()
window.update()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code works for me. Are you sure you saved the file before running it and are running the correct file?

Comment: Yes i did everything, but its not working.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It opens up a window with a large black canvas on it. Are you saying you don't see a large black area?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your canvas is showing up. You can see when u run your app, your bg color will be black. That's mean your code is working. However, If u want to build responsive frames use **pack(fill="both",expand=1)** or  **grid(sticky="nsew")** they will more useful in the future. If I were u I would build like that. You can test your code with changing canvas bgcolor.

Full code

```
import tkinter
import random

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Snake")
window.geometry(("625x625"))
window.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(
    window,
    bg="black",
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
)
canvas.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
window.update()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP wants to do some tile graphics with specified grid size, so your proposal on *responsive design* will break OP design.